# qml TextMetrics does not lay out spaces the same as Text

Tags: qml

**TextMetrics** is supposed to tell you the size of a rendered text string, but it does not seem to match how text is actually rendered by **Text**, especially if the string includes spaces.  The problem is very bad with certain fonts and `pointSize` or `pixelSize` settings, but vanishes with other fonts or sizes.

The following code creates Retangles with exactly the same height and width as the `boundingRect` returned by TextMetrics, which is supposed to cover every pixel of the rendered text.

But these Rectangles are slightly *narrower* than the rendered text, causing the last character to hang outside the Rectangle, where it is overlayed by the next Rectangle (the final 'd' character can be seen hanging out beyond the edge of the last Rectangle).

How to fix this?

**Is there a reliable way to know *exactly* the bounding box for a rendered text string?**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 100
    color: "grey"

    TextMetrics {
        id: metrics
        font.family: "Helvetica" // or try "Ubuntu"
        //font.pixelSize: 12
        font.pointSize: 14
        text: "H                      d"  // more spaces causes more corruption
    }

    Row {
        Repeater {
            model: 5
            Rectangle {
                clip: false
                color: "yellow"
                width: metrics.boundingRect.width
                height: metrics.boundingRect.height
                Text {
                    text: metrics.text
                    font: metrics.font
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just tried your example on Windows with Qt 5.9.1 and it works as expected!
So I guess it could be a Linux related bug maybe

Comment: `Text` and `TextMetrics` use some different assumptions, I've not been able to fully understand. Other options are, you can use `Text` instead of `TextMetrics` and hide it off the screen or zero opacity. Or create a temporary `Text` item using Qt.createQmlObject(), measure its width (save its `implicitWidth` property), then call destroy() on it. Not ideal, but it works

Answer (score 0):

@MarkCh's solution in the question's comments is the one that worked for me, while being simpler than adding a `TextMetrics` element. This is my full solution:

```
Rectangle {
    clip: false
    color: "yellow"
    width: text.contentWidth
    height: text.contentHeight
    Text {
        id: text
        text: "H                      d"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```